# Live camera in background (ios)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, camera

Is it possible to have the camera running in the background (using multitasking) and send live video feed somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not using public APIs. Maybe not even jailbroken, I don't know.